# Google cloud function, how to set the keyFile path and avoid error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api

I have created a cloud function that uses the Gmail API to send me an email. The cloud function is triggered by a google cloud scheduler. When I test this locally, it seems to work but when I upload my function to the Google cloud function code editor and upload it, there is an error in the logs. Note that the function seems to deploy fine and is active.

This is the error from the logs:

[image]

I am not sure what keyFile it is refering to or how to set it. This is my code:

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */


 const {google} = require('googleapis');
 const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
 
 const gmail = google.gmail('v1');
 
 const sendMail = async () => {
   // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
   const auth = await authenticate(
     process.env.client_id,
     process.env.client_secret,
     [
       'https://mail.google.com/',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
     ],
   );
   google.options({auth});
 
   // You can use UTF-8 encoding for the subject using the method below.
   // You can also just use a plain string if you don't need anything fancy.
   const subject = ' Hello ';
   const utf8Subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString('base64')}?=`;
   const messageParts = [
     'From: Oamar Kanji <oamarkanji@gmail.com',
     'To: Oamar Kanji <oamarkanji@gmail.com>',
     'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
     'MIME-Version: 1.0',
     `Subject: ${utf8Subject}`,
     '',
     'This is a message just to say hello.',
     'So... <b>Hello!</b>  ❤️',
   ];
   const message = messageParts.join('\n');
 
   // The body needs to be base64url encoded.
   const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
     .toString('base64')
     .replace(/\+/g, '-')
     .replace(/\//g, '_')
     .replace(/=+$/, '');
 
   const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
     userId: 'me',
     requestBody: {
       raw: encodedMessage,
     },
   });
   console.log(res.data);
   return res.data;
 }
 
 exports.alertPubSub = async (event, context) => {
 
    await sendMail()

 };
```

Comment: It seems as if you haven't even read the code that you've pasted ...

Comment: Where is the keyfile in your code?

Comment: I am using env variables to set the gmail client I’d and secret. Where would the key file go and what would it need to be? Thanks

Comment: @MartinZeitler, please expand on that comment

Comment: @OamarKanji please see this [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/local-auth), you are missing the key file to the parameter when using `@google-cloud/local-auth`.